io.ktor.client.request.forms.InputProvider to MultipartFile
I have an open api spec for an endpoint which accepts multipart form data(pdf, html, json files) and uploads that to a S3 bucket.
Using this open api spec, I'm generating both client and server(controller) code using kotlin generator for the endpoint mentioned above and the generated code looks as shown below.
Using kotlin-spring for generating server side code.
Using kotlin for generating client side code.
Just FYI the reason I have defined the type of the properties as object is because, if I don't(If I define it as string), due to a know bug in Kotlin open api generator, in the server side controller code, it messes up with the field name. More details in this link - OpenAPI Generation not respecting field name for multipart multifile upload However, I'm not sure if there is a work around other than defining it as object. Please suggest if there is one.
Open API spec:
  requestBody:
    required: true
    content:
      multipart/form-data:
        schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            code:
              type: string
            name:
              type: string
            fileCount:
              type: integer
            file1:
              type: object
              format: binary
              description: PDF file to upload
            file2:
              type: object
              format: binary
              description: JSON file to upload
            file3:
              type: object
              format: binary
              description: HTML file to upload
          required:
            - code
            - fileCount
            - file1
        encoding:
          file1:
            contentType: application/pdf, application/json, application/html
          file2:
            contentType: application/pdf, application/json, application/html
          file3:
            contentType: application/pdf, application/json, application/html

Generated Client Code:
open suspend fun upload(
        code: kotlin.String,
        fileCount: kotlin.Int,
        name: kotlin.String?,
        file1: io.ktor.client.request.forms.InputProvider,        
        file2: io.ktor.client.request.forms.InputProvider?,
        file3: io.ktor.client.request.forms.InputProvider?
    ): HttpResponse<Unit> {

        val localVariableAuthNames = listOf<String>("TokenBasedAuth")

        val localVariableBody =
            formData {
                code?.apply { append("code", code) }
                name?.apply { append("name", name) }
                fileCount?.apply { append("fileCount", fileCount.toString()) }
                file1?.apply { append("file1", file1.toString()) }
                file2?.apply { append("file2", file2.toString()) }
                file3?.apply { append("file3", file3.toString()) }
            }

        val localVariableQuery = mutableMapOf<String, List<String>>()

        val localVariableHeaders = mutableMapOf<String, String>()

        val localVariableConfig = RequestConfig<kotlin.Any?>(
            RequestMethod.POST,
            "/abc/xyz/",
            query = localVariableQuery,
            headers = localVariableHeaders,
            requiresAuthentication = true,
        )

        return multipartFormRequest(
            localVariableConfig,
            localVariableBody,
            localVariableAuthNames
        ).wrap()
    }

Generated ServerSide(Controller) Code:
@RequestMapping(
       method = [RequestMethod.POST],
       value = ["/abc/xyx"],
       produces = ["application/json"],
       consumes = ["multipart/form-data"]
   )
   fun upload(
       @RequestParam(value = "code", required = true) code: kotlin.String,
       @RequestParam(value = "fileCount", required = true) fileCount: kotlin.Int,
       @RequestParam(value = "file1", required = true) file1: kotlin.Any,
       @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) name: kotlin.String?,
       @RequestParam(value = "file2", required = false) file2: kotlin.Any?,
       @RequestParam(value = "file3", required = false) file3: kotlin.Any?
   ): ResponseEntity<Unit> {
       return getDelegate().upload(code, fileCount, file1, name, file2, file3)
   }

When I use the above generated client to call the endpoint, on the server side, the values for the file1, file2, and file3 are received as io.ktor.client.request.forms.InputProvider
I expected the generator to use MultipartFile instead of InputProvider. Not sure if there is a way to enforce it during client code generation.
However, that is not the primary concern. On the server side, I'm not sure how to extract/construct back the pdf file sent from the client side from InputProvider object on the server side and upload it to s3. I have attached the screenshot of the evaluated value of file from my intellij for reference. Any code references or help is much appreciated.


As far as I understand, you don't have the InputProvider on the server side because it's Ktor's class, not Spring's, so your question isn't clear to me. Also, the generated code seems incorrect because, for the files, it appends the string representation of the InputProvider (file1?.apply { append("file1", file1.toString()) }).

The server side in our case use ktor client to call other endpoints. Hence has ktor in its class path along with spring dependency. If you could see the screen shot I attached earlier it is from the server side. I 100% agree with you that there is something wrong with the client code generated which is what I’m not sure about and that is part of my question.

Also, for more context. I'm using the following configuration in open api generator to generate the client code. generatorNaem - Kotlin and library - jvm-ktor. I observed, if I change the library to multiplatform the generated client code doesn't have the toString() on the file1. I will give this a shot and will keep you posted. Thanks.
